# Use of metric prefixes for small numbers

Tags: word-usage, numbers, abbreviations, terminology, prefixes

These days many I see many websites shortening large numbers with the [metric prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix), for example Twitter does it like this:

[image]

replacing **35 400** with **35.4K**, and **34 700 000** with **34.7M**. One might also write the current year as **2k17** (though I don't understand what's the point of this as it doesn't save any letters).

Am I also allowed to use the same principle for shortening small quantities with the corresponding metric prefixes, like **0.0042** with **4.2m** (**m** for milli) or **0.0000042** with **4.2μ** (**μ** for micro)?

I'm primarily asking for the technical and scientific fields, but if you can also elaborate on usage in everyday life, this would be a nice addition.

Comment: You can, but no-one outside of a technical field will have the slightest idea what you mean! "Mu" is far from idiomatic, I'm afraid, and the difference between upper- and lower-case **m** will be lost on most readers outside of techical fields (and on some within them). (Also, "prefix" is counterintuitive here, because the notation is used as a _suffix_ to the number.)

Comment: @Max No, in my example with Twitter there is no units, just plain numbers, and the metric prefixes are used regardless. **4.2 meters** should be written with a *whitespace* (**4.2 m**), as physical unit is always separated from the value, so there should be no confusion between **4.2m** and **4.2 m**.

Comment: You say there should be no confusion, but I don't think the rule about whitespace is like a universally well understood rule. If you wrote "I walked 4.2m yesterday" I wouldn't think it's weird.

Comment: @SenjougaharaHitagi I'm afraid it is a universal rule. There was a [discussion on English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2794/punctuation-with-units) regarding this topic. Absence of space between the value and the unit only signifies how illiterate the person is.

Comment: English has no governing body deciding what is correct. There are also degrees to which something is wrong. I'm just describing to you how I think most native English speakers would react. If you wrote "I walkzd 4.2 m yesterday", like 100% of the people would think "why is there a z there" or "this must be a typo". If you wrote "I walked 4.2m yesterday" maybe 10% of people who are grammar nazi will say it's wrong and cast judgement upon your soul, but the all the well adjusted individuals will not care.

Comment: I don't think there are many cases in everyday life where you would use a unit-less non-fraction number (significantly) smaller than 1. And in technical/scientific fields every field has its own standards for units, but a unit-less number would usually be either spelled out, or written using scientific notation (e.g. 3,5 * 10^6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. For a journal or some specific target audience, I would go with whatever convention they use. In many cases, I could see μ being appropriate, but in other cases, they'd probably prefer *10<sup>-6</sup>.

For a post on the internet, or chat apps, I would avoid "m". If you wrote "I wouldn't want to be there for even 4m seconds", people might understand, but it's far from being conventional.